# jquery animate() divs open

Tags: jquery, animation

I want to make an animation in jquery: on hover the two divs change position, and on mouseout they return to they old position. (the first div goes up, the second goes down, then (on mouse out) return)

Problem: these divs are going up-down continously (i think, all of the events occurs)

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#container_wm" ).hover(function() {
  $( "#w" ).animate({
    marginTop: "-=100px"
  });
   $( "#m" ).animate({
    marginTop: "+=100px"
  });
});

$( "#container_wm" ).mouseout(function() {
  $( "#w" ).animate({
    marginTop: "+=100px"
  });
  $( "#m" ).animate({
    marginTop: "-=100px"
  });
});

});
```

ps.: thanks for help, and sorry for grammar mistakes

Comment: welcome to SO, could you show your markup or even better create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: post your html markup

Comment: @user3327181 please dont you hover, mouseout use mouseenter and mouseleave.. please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use the **hover**.. use the **mouseenter** event.

dont use the **mouseout**.. use the **mouseleave** event.

it will solve your problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#parentDiv").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).stop(true);
        $("#child1").animate({marginTop:'-=100px'});
        $("#child2").animate({marginTop:'+=100px'});
    })
    $("#parentDiv").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).stop(true);
        $("#child1").animate({marginTop:'+=100px'});
        $("#child2").animate({marginTop:'-=100px'});
    })
})
```

it will work for you..!!

Comment: @Gian this stop() not gonna make anyeffect check it once again.

Answer (score 0):

> It is simple. Use this code at the beginning of each animation
>   process.

```
$( "#container_wm" ).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).stop(true);
  $( "#w" ).animate({
    marginTop: "+=100px"
  });
```

`$(this).stop(true);` // Prevents animation on repeating

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution !

**HTMl**

```
<div id="container_wm">Hover me</div>
<div id="w"></div>
<div id="m"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container_wm { width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:#fff; cursor:pointer;}
    #w { position:absolute; left:200px; top:50px; width:100px; height:100px; background:yellow;}
    #m { position:absolute; left:200px; top:150px; width:100px; height:100px; background:green;}
```

**Code**

```
$('#container_wm').mouseover(function(){
    $('#w').animate({marginTop:'-=100px'});
    $('#m').animate({marginTop:'+=100px'});
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#w').animate({marginTop:'+=100px'});
    $('#m').animate({marginTop:'-=100px'});
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BDvMn/)

Answer (score 0):

check this [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/ze2RS/2/), you need to change `hover` to `mouseenter`.

javascript

> $(document).ready(function () {
>
> ```
> 'use strict';
>
> var space = 15;
> $("#container_wm").mouseenter(function () {
>     $("#w").animate({
>         top: "-=" + space + "px"
>     });
>
>     $("#m").animate({
>         top: "+=" + space + "px"
>     });
> });
>
> $("#container_wm").mouseout(function () {
>     $("#w").animate({
>         top: "+=" + space + "px"
>     });
>
>     $("#m").animate({
>         top: "-=" + space + "px"
>     });
> });
> ```
>
> });